# A method of discriminant of cubic: a problem in proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

This is from an exercise in Galois theory by Cox.

Let $f(y)=y^3+py+q=(y-y_1)(y-y_2)(y-y_3)$ and $\Delta:=(y_1-y_2)^2(y_2-y_3)^2(y_3-y_1)^2$.

**Claim:** $\Delta=-4p^3-27q^2$.

**Proof:** $f'(y_1)=3y_1^2+p=(y_1-y_2)(y_1-y_3)$.

Therefore, $\Delta=-f'(y_1)f'(y_2)f'(y_3)$ [Easy to see].

How should I proceed after this?

**Difficulty:** $3y_1^2+p=(y_1-y_2)(y_1-y_3)$. We can replace $y_1$ by a dummy variable $x$ to get
$$3x^2+p=(x-y_2)(x-y_3)$$
which tells that $y_2,y_3$ are roots of the left quadratic, which should therefore be among $\{\sqrt{-p/3}, -\sqrt{-p/3}\}$.

Now, the same justification will tell us that $y_1,y_3$ (and $y_1,y_2$) lie in the set  $\{\sqrt{-p/3}, -\sqrt{-p/3}\}$.

But, if three members $y_1,y_2,y_3$ belong to set $\{\sqrt{-p/3}, -\sqrt{-p/3}\}$, then two of them will be equal, so $\Delta$ should be $0$, which shows that I am wrong in some arguments (which I was not able to catch).

Further, the equations
$$3y_1^2+p=(y_1-y_2)(y_1-y_3), \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, 3y_2^2+p=(y_2-y_1)(y_2-y_3), \,\,\,\,\,\,\, 3y_3^2+p=(y_3-y_1)(y_3-y_2)$$
show that the right sides have connection only with $p$; and consequently $\Delta$ should depend only on $p$, which is also creating confusion.

Please give some simple questions of the type *Prove this* to prove the claim, and also point out my mistakes in above understanding.

Comment: there is an explicit formula for the discriminant $Res(f,f')$ - the "Sylvester formula" - where the determinant of an explicit matrix gives the discriminant. Look up "Sylvester formula".

Comment: The relation where you are trying to replace $y_1$ by $x$ is actually valid only for $y_1$. You can not move from a specific identity to a general one. Same remark applies for $f'(y_2),f'(y_3)$. The general identity is more complicated namely $f'(x) =(x-y_1)(x-y_2)+(x-y_2)(x-y_3)+(x-y_3)(x-y_1)$ which is obtained by differentiating $f(x) =(x-y_1)(x-y_2)(x-y_3)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You cannot just replace $y_1$ with a general $x.$ The formula for $f'(x)$ has a term $(x-y_1)(x-y_2)$ and a term $(x-y_1)(x-y_3)$ both of which happen to cancel for $x=y_1.$
2. You know that $\Delta = -(3y_1^2 + p)(3y_2^2 + p)(3y_3^2 + p).$ Expand out and use Vieta's formulas to derive the discriminant formula; the expansion is not so bad.

Comment: Sorry, (1) is not clear to me. (2) is ok.